# Get Id of user currently logged into MS Dynamics CRM 2011 Online

Tags: javascript, c#, dynamics-crm-2011, kentico

Is there a way to retrieve/identify the user that is currently logged into MS Dynamics CRM 2011 Online?

What i'm trying to accomplish here is kind of like the facebook login except with MS Dynamics. I need to somehow detect whether the user has logged into the MS Dynamics website. If the user is logged into the MS Dynamics website, i'll have to grab the UserId and authenticate it with Kentico CMS.

I've tried messing with the WhoAmIRequest, but unfortunately it needs a credential to properly execute.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get userid from context. Recheck this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334511.aspx#BKMK_getUserId).

Comment: Hi Andrii, this is great! But I need to grab this user id and use it inside the global.asax code. But since the client script runs after the server script, i don't think this solution would work. 

Unless i could find a way to grab the user id from global.asax file

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Currently Logged in User Id by

```
 WhoAmIRequest request = new WhoAmIRequest();
            WhoAmIResponse response = (WhoAmIResponse)Service.Execute(request);
            if (response != null)
                return response.UserId;
```

You can create a default service like:

```
ClientCredentials Credentials = new ClientCredentials();
Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
//This URL needs to be updated to match the servername and Organization for the environment.


Uri OrganizationUri = new Uri("http://crm/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");

Uri HomeRealmUri = null;

//OrganizationServiceProxy serviceProxy; 

OrganizationServiceProxy serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(OrganizationUri, HomeRealmUri, Credentials, null)

IOrganizationService service = (IOrganizationService)serviceProxy;
```

Comment: Hi Dot_NET Junior, I've tried that, but when creating a service it requires me to insert a credentials. The problem is i don't know what the credentials is, so i have to find a way to detect the cookie that was created by the Dynamics CRM 2011.

I'm still fairly new to this so please forgive me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @LucasLim Hi yes you are right,,, 

So for creating a service you use default credentials of the logged in User...